# Magnolia CMS "jumping cursor"

Tags: magnolia

when in the Magnolia UI a click/double click on a node provokes a redraw of the UI. That wouldn't be bad if after the click the focus would still be the same but instead your are being thrown to a *random* node as the focus. Its frustrating to work with because with a big structure like we have, for *every* click you need to scroll and look again for the node you want to work with.
I googled extensively but have found no clue how to fix this behaviour.
It happens in Chrome  56.0.2924.87 as well as in Firefox 52.0.2 (64-Bit)

Any idea would be welcomed, this is really annoying.

Best wishes,
Chris

Comment: Hey there, What magnolia version are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you hit to https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-4084,
this has been fixed since 5.5.2. Please try to update and see if that works for you.

If unfortunately that's not the case, please feel free to report it to Magnolia.

Cheers,